# Multi-column autoflow

Tags: html, css

So I'm building out a design for a client for a single-page newsletter site. Attached is the concept [here](http://personal.justgooddesign.net/dailydose/DailyDose.jpg) and I have everything built out except the actual main copy. The idea is that they add in new news every day, and what they want to do is have a simple page that has basic styling markup applied to the news, that will then get sucked into the page via AJAX or something similar. However, with the column format, they want the columns to be auto-created by some method applied when the content is getting sucked into the page. Each news story preview will be the same length and formatting. My question is, is it possible to have columns auto-created that are a specific height and width and just have them be auto-created until they run out of copy? I'm a graphic designer with only experience in HTML and CSS, so I'm looking for solutions that are within my abilities. Thank you for any suggestions anyone might have! At this point I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Here is the current page I have up: http://personal.justgooddesign.net/dailydose/
What I want is for a new column to be created with each h2 element. Here's a sample of the code:

```
<h1>Top News Stories for November 11, 2011</h1>
<hr color="#fe0000" />
<h2>Coffee growers in Uganda and elsewhere find climate change hurting their crops</h2>
A farmer near Uganda's Mount Elgon holds Arabica coffee berries. It's getting more difficult to grow coffee berries because of erratic weather patterns. (Photo by Jill Braden Balderas.) In Uganda, the coffee trees are nearly empty — and it's not ...
<br /><a href="http://www.pri.org" target="_blank">http://www.pri.org</a>

<h2>Exclusive: Europe coffee buyers upset at Liffe delivery delays</h2>
Some companies that urgently need robusta coffee -- used mostly in blends and instant coffee and the second largest grown variety after arabica coffee -- are scrambling to find other sources. Many are turning to the spot market and effectively paying ...
<br />
<a href="http://www.reuters.com" target="_blank">http://www.reuters.com</a>

<h2>Asia Coffee: Vietnam Slow to Sell, Indonesia Premiums Dip</h2>
Robusta coffee beans are roasted at the Losari Coffee Plantation in Magelang, Central Java, Indonesia, on Saturday, Sept. 18, 2010. Indonesia is the largest Asian coffee grower after Vietnam. (Bloomberg Photo/ Dimas Ardian) Singapore. ...
<br />
<a href="http://www.thejakartaglobe.com" target="_blank">http://www.thejakartaglobe.com</a>

<h2>Coffee Cupping</h2>
By Rachel Gibian and Nicole J. Levin, CONTRIBUTING WRITERS With a metal spoon and the steady hands of a surgeon, Jaime Vanschyndel, general manager of Barismo, gently pushes aside the coffee grounds that have floated to the surface of the cup. ...
<br />
<a href="http://www.thecrimson.com" target="_blank">http://www.thecrimson.com</a>

<h2>Espresso cups outsell mugs</h2>
Britain's coffee revolution has claimed another victim: the humble mug. According to two leading department stores, sales of espresso cups are now outselling mugs for the first time, as more and more households switch to using coffee machines. ...
<br />
<a href="http://www.telegraph.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.telegraph.co.uk</a>

<h2>Specialty coffee abounds in Austin</h2>
Austin has a number of local coffee outlets that specialize in roasting their own beans, providing much needed caffeination for countless Austinites. Third Coast Coffee is a fair trade coffee house that serves up many Austinites on a daily basis. ...
<br />
<a href="http://www.dailytexanonline.com" target="_blank">http://www.dailytexanonline.com</a>

<img src="IMG/main-banner_2.jpg" id="ad-b" />

<h1>For Roasters and Retailers</h1>
<hr color="#fe0000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You could use divs that are 50% width and float, like this:</strike>

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myn3h/

**CSS**

```
#Container {
    overflow: auto;
}

.NewsItem {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Container">
    <div class="NewsItem">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="NewsItem">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..
        </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="NewsItem">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..
        </p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Update**

You could try CSS3 multi column layout. It's just not widely supported yet:

```
#container {
 -moz-column-width: 13em; 
 -webkit-column-width: 13em; 
 -moz-column-gap: 1em; 
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

CSS3.info Reference: [multi column layout](http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/) 
W3C reference: [CSS multi-column layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)
caniuse reference: [multiple column layout](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20column)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! A manual method like that is definitely on my list, but ideally I'd like to find a way where the columns are auto-generated because the person who will be doing the news on a daily basis does not know HTML and they're rather adamant that they will not hire someone else to do it. (Clients, ya know.)

Comment: I was going to add this as an answer but think a comment is more appropriate. I've been looking for something similar for a Drupal 7 custom formatter that I thought would be a handy thing to have around. The problem I ran into (and still haven't found an answer for) isn't splitting the columns, but splitting them so they don't break any HTML tags in the text.